# Cannot deploy Firebase to Heroku

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku, google-cloud-functions

I've been using firebase-functions for some time now to send notifications when data in my real-time database change. The response times are slower than I would hope for though, so I want to test out the speed when running firebase-functions from my a Heroku server.

I created a new directory where I ran `firebase init`, selected `functions` and installed npm dependencies.

Next, within the `/functions` folder, I ran `npm i --save firebase-functions@latest` to install firebase-functions.

Finally, I connected the directory to my newly created heroku app, and when I commited the files and pushed them to the server, after the app started running, it gives me an error saying:

```
2018-01-25T12:46:36.067188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-01-25T12:46:38.760835+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-25T12:46:38.760864+00:00 app[web.1]: > functions@ start /app
2018-01-25T12:46:38.760866+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run shell
2018-01-25T12:46:38.760867+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-25T12:46:39.349173+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-25T12:46:39.349185+00:00 app[web.1]: > functions@ shell /app
2018-01-25T12:46:39.349187+00:00 app[web.1]: > firebase experimental:functions:shell
2018-01-25T12:46:39.349188+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-25T12:46:39.369290+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: firebase: not found
2018-01-25T12:46:39.376687+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-01-25T12:46:39.377392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-01-25T12:46:39.377799+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-01-25T12:46:39.378259+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-01-25T12:46:39.381157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! functions@ shell: `firebase experimental:functions:shell`
2018-01-25T12:46:39.381440+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-01-25T12:46:39.382004+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-01-25T12:46:39.382312+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ shell script.
2018-01-25T12:46:39.382734+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-01-25T12:46:39.394334+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-25T12:46:39.394784+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-01-25T12:46:39.395010+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-25T12_46_39_386Z-debug.log
2018-01-25T12:46:39.406074+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-01-25T12:46:39.409741+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-01-25T12:46:39.411510+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! functions@ start: `npm run shell`
2018-01-25T12:46:39.411748+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-01-25T12:46:39.416294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-01-25T12:46:39.416538+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ start script.
2018-01-25T12:46:39.416788+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-01-25T12:46:39.430670+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-25T12:46:39.431270+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-01-25T12:46:39.432272+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-25T12_46_39_423Z-debug.log
2018-01-25T12:46:39.491615+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-01-25T12:46:39.505425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm having great difficulty setting up my own firebase-functions on Heroku and cannot seem to find a relevant guide online.

Comment: So basically you want to treat your Firebase Functions as Node.js module or app, right? Whoa, I am not sure that the process is that straightforward. I believe that Firebase Functions is actually running some Exress.js and the deployment is somewhat specific. I would guess you have to setup your Heroku Node.js a bit more. Did you just pushed your local package to your hosting or what exactly you mean by "connected the directory...commited the files and pushed"? What resources do you have then available and in what form?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Emocuc. I pushed the contents in my `/functions` folder. I'm hoping the improve the performance by running the functions somewhere other than the firebase servers which give me a delay of 10-15 seconds before notification on my device is received. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: :D oh yeah, I know it was not helpful, sorry ... but the issue sounds challenging ... well I think that if you want to move out of Firebase, then do it completely and do not overload yourself by trying to mix things up together ... If you like Heroku, build your app there or look for other solutions, I bet you already searched for Firebase alternatives.

Comment: After thinking about your proposal a bit, I think, it is near to impossible to achieve. Since the Firebase Functions are in fact Google Cloud Functions and there are many highly specific things  on that platform, such as the triggers and internal communication, you would have to write a lot of things yourself and manage to connect to your stack remotely - not really sure you want to do that, I would not. If Firebase does not work for you, move to another platform. Many guys did. These had similar motivations to yours https://crisp.chat/blog/why-you-should-never-use-firebase-realtime-database/